# Не завершать скрипт при ошибке

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Запускаю скрипт следующей командой:

> node script.js

в скрипте есть такой код:

```
 do {
        await axios.post('https://example.com/test.php', 
            qs.stringify({
                id: id_product,
                page: html_page
            })
        ).then(function (response) {
            console.log( id_product+' ok;' );
        });
  
  await setTimeout(60000);
  } while (1);
```

Иногда бывает что https://example.com/test.php выдает ошибку 500, и тогда скрипт node у меня перестает выполнятся.

Как сделать чтобы если произошла ошибка, чтобы скрипт просто продолжил выполняться дальше

Comment: Посмотреть [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) и добавить обработчик ошибки. Он может ничего не обрабатывать, но предотвратит "падение" приложения.

Comment: try catch obernut